# javascript array inside object inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want an array of objects, and each object has a string, an array of strings and an integer...

Isn't this right?

```
var ques = [
    {
        "q": "quest1",
        "a": ["ans1", "ans2", "ans3", "ans4"],
        "c": 1
    },
    {
        "q": "quest4",
        "a": ["ans1", "ans2", "ans3"],
        "c": 3
    },
    {
        "q": "quest7",
        "a": ["ans1", "ans2"],
        "c": 2
    }
];
```

Comment: What is the problem now?

Comment: Why are you posting this? did you encounter any problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is a valid array of objects.

Comment: Ok, i had an error when trying to reach an item from the inner array... sorry for the useless question!